# Trying to write tests for React/Next.js api using axios

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

I am newish to React and I am trying to write some tests for my code but keep running into a issue when using mock api's with axios. The app is build using next.js

Api route

```
import axios from "axios";

export default async function movies_trending(req, res) {
  const url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/movie/week";
  const response = await axios.get(url, {
    params: {
      api_key: process.env.TMDB_API,
    },
  });
  res.json({ response: response.data.results });
}
```

index.js

```
import MovieCourasel from "@/components/MovieCarousel";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Index(props) {
  const { trending } = props;
  console.log(trending)
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Whats Trending</h1>
      <MovieCourasel movies={trending.response} />
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "http://localhost:3000/api/movies/trending/"
  );
  return {
    props: { trending: response.data },
  };
}
```

index.test.js

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import Index from "@/pages/index";

describe("Index components", () => {
  test("renders heading trending", async () => {
    axios.get = jest.fn();
    axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({
        response: [
          {
            adult: false,
            backdrop_path: "/2Icjry0xdRSNxrtsBR1F47b9r3u.jpg",
            id: 615656,
            title: "Meg 2: The Trench",
            original_language: "en",
            original_title: "Meg 2: The Trench",
            overview:
              "An exploratory dive into the deepest depths of the ocean of a daring research team spirals into chaos when a malevolent mining operation threatens their mission and forces them into a high-stakes battle for survival.",
            poster_path: "/4m1Au3YkjqsxF8iwQy0fPYSxE0h.jpg",
            media_type: "movie",
            genre_ids: [28, 878, 27],
            popularity: 8742.665,
            release_date: "2023-08-02",
            video: false,
            vote_average: 6.977,
            vote_count: 1062,
          },
        ],
    });

    render(<Index />);
    const headingElement = screen.getByText("whats trending", { exact: false });
    expect(headingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'response')

       8 |     <>
       9 |       <h1>Whats Trending</h1>
    > 10 |       <MovieCourasel movies={trending.response} />
         |                                       ^
      11 |     </>
      12 |   );
      13 | }
```

I used axios in vanilla react before without any problems. Not sure if there is a config issues or if my mock response is wrong. Any help would be appriciated

Comment: @RobinThomas, sorry for my late answer. It seems to work fine until I include the index component. I get the feeling, it is the serverSideProps that might be causing the issue, I am still trying to figure out how the info should be passed into the Index component

Comment: I think my understanding is still limited but when logging the axios.get.mock... it is undefined, so the trending props passed to index is undefined which is then passed to the MovieCourasel. I removed the axios mock and just passed a normal object with fake data and ts passes, but that does not feel like a valid way of testing things.

Comment: I understood your issue. Have updated my answer. Please check if it works fine for you.

Comment: @RobinThomas yes this works, Not sure it it is the correct flow, but actually the mock did not return anything, so I could not pass the props. Doing it like this is good, I suppose it is okay to test components, but will try and figure out the correct way to test serverSideProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues in your `index.test.js` file.

1. You need to have a `jest.mock("axios")` at the top. This shall be hoisted to the top by jest, and shall be executed before your `import` statement.
2. The response from your mock is not correct. You need to return `data.results`.
3. The more important issue is that `getServerSideProps` is not executed automatically. That needs to be call manually from your tests.

As such, rather than mocking `axios`, simply pass the expected response as props to the `Index` component.

```
describe("Index components", () => {
  test("renders heading trending", async () => {
    const props = {
      trending: {
        response: [
          {
            adult: false,
            backdrop_path: "/2Icjry0xdRSNxrtsBR1F47b9r3u.jpg",
            id: 615656,
            // ...other fields
          },
        ],
      },
    }

    render(Index(props));
    const headingElement = screen.getByText("whats trending", { exact: false });
    expect(headingElement).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```